# Laravel: BindingResolutionException using Schema\Blueprint and Builder

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create a Laravel application that creates custom tables and columns in my database in order to store user generated forms data (a custom Survey application).

I am trying to use Builder and Blueprint and create a custom class upon that (as I already did with FormBuilder).

Example:

```
namespace Acme\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder;

class AnswersTableBuilder {

    private $builder;
    private $blueprint;

    public function __construct(Builder $builder, Blueprint $blueprint)
    {
        $this->builder = $builder;
        $this->blueprint = $blueprint;
    }

[...]
```

However when I try to use it in my controller, for example:

```
use Acme\Validators\SurveyValidator;
use Acme\Repos\Survey\SurveyRepository;
use Acme\Repos\Section\SectionRepository;
use Acme\Helpers\AnswersTableBuilder;


class SurveysController extends \BaseController {

    private $surveyRepo;
    private $sectionRepo;
    private $tableBuilder;

    public function __construct(SurveyRepository $survey, SectionRepository $section, AnswersTableBuilder $tableBuilder)
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('only' => array('store', 'destroy', 'update')));
        $this->surveyRepo = $survey;
        $this->sectionRepo = $section;
        $this->tableBuilder = $tableBuilder;
    }

[...]
```

I get an error:

```
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $dsn ]].
```

I seem to be able to use the IoC container for most of my classes, maybe something wrong with the ones I am using as dependencies here? Tried changing the entries in my service provider but it didn't help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint` and `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder`, both classes have dependencies as well (The first one need the table name only and the latter need a instance of Illuminate\Database\Connection).

Maybe you could try to inject them as well?